How to establish BLE connection without going through SMP process in single ended Bluetooth pairing
After pairing and connecting an Android phone and a Windows computer on the Bluetooth settings page, open the phone's Bluetooth interface to release the pairing with the computer. At this point, using the computer to initiate a BLE connection to the phone will trigger the SMP encryption process. When attempting data exchange, a key missing message will be reported, and then the PC will disconnect on its own. What Windows API can be used to establish a connection without triggering the SMP encryption process or using other methods to disconnect without reporting a key missing message and allow data exchange to proceed normally?
I tried setting the ProtectionLevel of GattCharacteristic to the lowest level and also tried GattSession MaintainConnection (true) was used to maintain the connection, and attempts were made to use APIs such as GetGattServicesAsync(), GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode), GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(Guid), GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(Guid, BluetoothCacheMode) to initiate the connection, but none of them could avoid key missing and disconnection

Does the BluetoothLE sample work for you?

No, I tried two cache modes using the same GetGattServices Asynchronous (Bluetooth CacheMode) as him, but it still executed the SMP process

I consulted the Bluetooth team and here is the response, Currently, Windows does not offer any API that lets the app knows that pairing has been removed from the phone side.
A clean way to handle this situation is to remove the pairing form Windows side and initiate the pairing process again.

Although from my view it is necessary to pair again, I still consulted the Bluetooth team.
It's time to make a conclusion and I attach the response.

What I understood from Stackoverflow is that, user has removed the
pairing from mobile phone’s end. Currently, Windows does not offer any
API that lets the app knows that pairing has been removed from the
phone side. A clean way to handle this situation is to remove the
pairing form Windows side and initiate the pairing process again.

For more information further, you can send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app about this condition.
